# django-cms user can't add pages

Tags: django-cms

django 1.5.1
django cms 2.4.2

i am just learning  django-cms and am working on my first test site.  I searched this site and googled for these questions but can't find any answers which is why I am posting here....  Any help would be appreciated!

Through the admin page (as superuser) i added a group with permission to add/change/delete pages in addition to other permissions.

I create a user and assign the user to this group.

First of all, if i don't specify that user as staff then they can't access the admin site to login to begin with - this just doesn't make sense to me:  what's the point of a user who never has the option to log in?  Or is there something I'm missing - is there another way to log in besides the admin site itself.

Second, after marking that user as staff, and keeping in mind that the user is a member of group with permission to add/edit/delete pages, when the user logs in he can perform other admin tasks that he was given permissions for but still can't add/edit/delete pages.  Although pages shows up as an object there is no link to the page list.

Answer (score 11):

The Staff setting is to differentiate between users who are allowed to access the Django admin and users who aren't i.e. regular users who have signed up to your website via a registration form.

I had the same problem as you creating a new non-superuser user and not being able to add or edit pages as that user. It turned out that I needed to set `CMS_PERMISSION = False` in my settings.py.

If `CMS_PERMISSION == True`, you get a more fine-grained permissions framework where each page has its own list of users who are allowed to view and edit it, so permission to edit is done on a page-by-page basis (unless you're a superuser). If you don't need that functionality, I suggest you turn it off.

If you do want the more fine-grained permissions system, but you also want some users to be able to edit any page on the site, log in to django admin as a superuser and look at Cms -> Pages global permissions. From there you can give blanket edit rights to any user or group.

Comment: I need page by page functionality. :(

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I ended up using the CMS -> Pages Global Permissions and a Group to manage this.